# is it possible that calling mysql stored procedure through Java API in sqoop2(1.99.7)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, java, sqoop2

is it possible that calling mysql stored procedure through Java API in sqoop2(1.99.7)??

i could found anything related calling stored-procedure in sqoop2..

anyone know that?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can that language issue arbitrary SQL queries?  If so, use `CALL`.